# How to set C1=D1 then clear D1 Google Sheets using App Script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm currently working on a Google Sheet and want to be able to set the value of cell C1 to be the value of cell D1, and then clear cell D1 afterward.

My issue is that once I clear cell D1, cell C1 is also cleared. I've tried using SpreadsheetApp.flush() to perform these operations one by one to see if that will fix my issue, but to no avail.

I can't seem to find a solution online, so any help is very much appreciated!

Below is a snippet of my code:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  // Check if the edit happened on a valid sheet.
  if (sheet.getName() == "Sheet2") {
    // Get info about the edited cell.
    var actRng = sheet.getActiveRange();
    var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
    var rowIndex = actRng.getRowIndex();

    // Get the column headers from row 1.
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

    // Set the column (by name) that will have the new sell set.
    var baseSellCol = headers[0].indexOf("Base Sell") + 1; // C1
    var newSellCol = headers[0].indexOf("Suggested Sell") +1; //D1

    // Set the "trigger" column that the user adjusts to trigger the new sell.
    var activityCol = headers[0].indexOf("Accept?") + 1; // E1

    // if E1 == "Yes" then C1 = D1 and D1.clear()
    if (baseSellCol > 0 && rowIndex > 1 && editColumn == activityCol && e.value == "Yes") {
      var base_sell = sheet.getRange(rowIndex, baseSellCol);
      var new_sell = sheet.getRange(rowIndex, newSellCol);
      var new_sell_value = new_sell.getValue();

      // Set Base Sell = Suggested Sell (C1 = D1)
      base_sell.setValue(new_sell_value);

      new_sell.clear(); // HELP: why is base_sell getting cleared when new_sell is cleared
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
    
  }
}
```

Here is a short video clip of how my code executes in Google Sheets: https://gyazo.com/db5038fde4e4c3c0f391ef613769d9b8

And here's a link to a copy of the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gbEimdeGvMXe7rTbmPJRv-iEjay0vdXMC66BfdZaGX8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). I cannot reproduce the behavior you describe in a copy of your sample spreadsheet. What I see is this: put `Yes` in `E2`. The value in `C2` changes to the same as that of `D2`. Cell `D2` is then cleared of content and formatting. The value in `C2` stays put. Make sure you do not have another script project with a trigger that clears `C2`.

Comment: @doubleunary After reading your comment, I took your advice and took a look at both sheets to see any differences between the two sheets. Sure enough, I added a manual Trigger on the original sheet that I had forgotten about. After deleting it, my original sheet operates just like the copy I linked. Thank you!!

Comment: OK. Adding that as an answer. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

The code you show does not clear cell `C2`, so chances are that have another script project (not shown) with a trigger that clears that cell. Remove the other trigger to sort out the issue. See [installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).